# How do I render a scene like it was taken from an iPhone camera?

Tags: camera

So I have a scene that I want to render so that results looks like it was kinda shot on an iPhone camera. What I've tried so far is using the focal length that I get from apple's camera intrinsics matrix, but that alone isn't giving me the results that I want.

So I was wondering if someone has played around with a project like this before and knows I could the zooms/zNear/zFar/distortions down and even what information I might need to collect from an actual iPhone camera so I know what range to set the parameters in.